# How can I keep using the same List<> throughout my program?

Tags: c#

I would like to store all my `snakes`, in a `snakeList`.

When the user creates new snakes, I would like the program to keep them, and store them in a `List`.

But I don't know how to do that.

If I write:

```
List<Snake> snakeList = new List<Snake>();
```

Then, whenever I restart the program, I think it creates a new `snakeList` every time.
I would like to keep using the same snake list, even if the program restarts.

Should I use `XML` for that?

Comment: Yup. You'll need to serialize the list of snakes when the program closes, and then deserialize it when the program loads up again. XML is a good way to go.

Comment: you need some sort of storage to persist the data.  A database, or an xml file on the file system - something.

Comment: I don't think you'd do too badly searching for `loading and saving data in C#` and reading a few articles/posts. I think there's too much to try to fit in an answer here.

Comment: Depending on the application, you COULD store it in session

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# .NET - method to store some very small scale persistent information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323755/c-sharp-net-method-to-store-some-very-small-scale-persistent-information)

Comment: It's a broad question that may be answer by : 1/. in database: A, sqlLite, no-db,..etc.. 2/. in file with format: csv, json, xml , etc. 3/. in session depending of your application type. Each of those question may also be too broad as there is a ton a possible database structure format.

Comment: @DannyGoodall Thank you! Probably that is what I will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to write data to external resource (file, database) in order to persist that data, even when app is closed.

So in order to do that, when program closes, you need to write it to disk, for example (I used serialization to JSON, you can use other method):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(snakeList.ToArray());

//write string to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path to file", json);
```

And on app start, you create your list initializing it from saved file. If file is not present, you just create empty list.

For that task you'd use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method.

Look at Json.Net.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c/16921677)